# PowerPoint 2016 - Do not enumerate hidden slides

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

I have hidden slides in my presentation, but the problem is that when I generate the PDF or I use the presentation mode of the PowerPoint, it enumerates the hidden slides and then, for instance, you jump from slide 37 to slide 39.

Is it possible to remove automatically the enumeration of hidden slides?

Comment: This is used as an example in [a meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376194/is-it-reasonable-to-ding-rep-because-someone-else-posted-incorrect-answers-to-a) (likely to be autodeleted within 30 days or so).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to create the slide numbers yourself (or by using a bit of VBA) rather than using PowerPoint's own slide numbering.

Answer (score 6):

As Steve Rindsberg said, you may use such a VBA macro as found here: [VBA : Number the slide if they are visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35266264/vba-number-the-slide-if-they-are-visible/35277025#35277025)

The necessary steps for me were

- saving the presentation in with-macros-format (as a file with dot-*pptm* ending)
- pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> (or on mac hit menu *Tools* → *Macros* → *Visual Basic Editor*)
- entering the code from aforementioned Stack Overflow answer
- pressing either <kbd>F5</kbd> or the green <kbd>run</kbd> arrow

Answer (score -3):

You can also create a custom Slide Show. Which will allow you to pick and choose which slides (from your existing presentation) you would like to use. Then from this new presentation you can create your pdf.

Comment: You can create a predetermined range of slides to print/save as PDF by creating a custom show, or you can enter the page numbers of the pages you want to print in the print dialog, but they'll STILL be numbered as though you're printing all of the slides, so this doesn't really solve CGGs problem.

Answer (score -5):

You can simply create a new section (Home- section) and put your hidden slides there. Then numbering will not include your hidden slides.